# What is the best way to wash away a bleach cleanser in the shower?

Tags: shower, cleaning

When I spray a bleach spray into my shower to destroy mildew growing on my shower tiles, I always have a hard time trying to rinse the cleanser solution off. My shower doesn't have a hose - the nozzle only sprays at a limited angle so I don't know how to wash away the other sides of the shower... Does anyone have any recommendation as how I should rinse of the remaining shower areas that still have bleach? I was just going to use a towel with water to try and wash it off but I feel like it would be too messy and I could easily get the bleach spray on myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best" is very subjective for this question. One's personal idea of best will not be everyone's. It depends also on what resources you have available. Here's some ideas, see if you like any, or maybe they'll inspire more ideas.

I just use my hand to deflect the shower spray, but this only works well with high velocity heads.

Fill a bucket with water and use a smaller container to splash water about.

Route a garden hose in from outside.

Use a watering can.

Use a well rinsed weed sprayer filled with plain water.